# Erratic Behavior in console for logging versus print messages

Tags: pydev

I am finding seemingly random ordering of print versus python logging outputs to the pydev console.
So for example here is my code:

```
import logging 
logging.warning('Watch out!') # will print a message to the console
print "foo"
logging.info('I told you so') # will not print anything
logging.warning("Event:")
logging.warning("told ya")
```

Note the print line around "foo".  What is bizzare is each time I run this the order of output with respect to foo changes! That is foo appears one time at the top another time in the middle another time at the end and so forth. 
 This is unfortunate in a less toy context when I want to know the sequence in which these output events occured in the code (e.g. when tracing/logging etc).  Any suggestions as to what might be going on? Latest pydev, python 2.7.6
 Thanks!

p.s. As a side-effect (probably) this is making an eclipse tool out there "grep console" behave oddly). But the problem I describe above is independent of that.

Comment: Did some more testing. If put time pauses around the foo the output behavior becomes stable. So somehow despite the serial order in the non 'paused' context perhaps logging and print are operating independently? (differently threaded?) Perhaps this is clarifying clue to someone cleverer than I :-)